# Convert Subversion commit messages to Unicode

Tags: windows, svn, encoding, utf-8, cp1251

Currently I have a local Subversion repository with a lot of commit messages in `cp1251` encoding.

Is there any way I can convert all commit messages into `utf-8` encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commit messasges [are already stored as UTF-8](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.initial.html):

> Subversion internally handles certain bits of data—for example, property names, pathnames, and log messages—as UTF-8-encoded Unicode. This is not to say that all your interactions with Subversion must involve UTF-8, though. As a general rule, Subversion clients will gracefully and transparently handle conversions between UTF-8 and the encoding system in use on your computer, if such a conversion can meaningfully be done (which is the case for most common encodings in use today).

If you've somehow double-encoded them, though, then assuming you're using an FSFS-style repository the easiest way will probably be to work through all the revprop files that you find in `db/revprops/*/*` underneath your repository and re-write them with the correct encoding, e.g. using the [iconv command-line tool from GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm). (Note that these files should have Unix line endings i.e. LF not CRLF).

Comment: I was looking into `revs` instead of `revprops` directory where log messages are indeed stored as UTF-8. Looks like the problem I'm having is actually with one of the console tool not working with UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: For input of output? If input, then you probably want `--encoding` as mazaneicha says; for output you might do better with the `--xml` output which is (supposed to be!) always UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

As Rup-8 says, subversion should convert all log messages to UTF-8 before storing them in the repository, and back to the local encoding for display. If your log messages aren't being converted correctly, either:

- Make sure your locale setting correctly identifies the encoding you're using; or,
- Use the --message-encoding option

Comment: Looks like it is actually a problem with one of the console tools not treating UTF-8 correctly rather than with SVN repository itself.